# edit an existing google map from an external js file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to edit all google maps from a page with an external js file.
Let's say that I have 5 pages with 3 google maps in every page. 
I want to add a circle in every google map.
How to do this from an external javascript file which will be loaded in every page?

Comment: please upload what you got to jsfiddle or something...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/viorel1166/8ofy2wcv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base page with multiple maps, and an external JS file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script>
var maps = [];
function drawMaps(){
    for(var i = 1; i<4;i++){
        drawMap(i);
    }
}
function drawMap(num){
    var mapcontainer=document.getElementById("map"+num);
    var options={
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.266323, -73.996579),
        zoom:8,
        maptypeid:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(mapcontainer,options);
    maps.push(map);
    var circle=new google.maps.Circle({
        map:map,
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.266323, -73.996579),
        radius:10000,
        fillColor:"blue",
        border:0,
        strokeWeight:0
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", drawMaps); 
</script>
<script src="externalJS.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="height:400px;width:400px" id="map1"></div> 
    <div style="height:400px;width:400px" id="map2"></div> 
    <div style="height:400px;width:400px" id="map3"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Note the array which serves as an accessible bin for all maps. Also notice the window listener for "load."

The external JS file contents:

```
function addToAllMaps(){
    if(maps!=undefined){
        for (var i in maps){
            var map = maps[i];
            var circle=new google.maps.Circle({
                    map:map,
                    center:new google.maps.LatLng(40.266323, -73.996579),
                    radius:1000000,
                    fillColor:"red",
                    border:0,
                    strokeWeight:0
                });
        }
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load", addToAllMaps);
```

Note how it references the maps array and applies the red circle to each in a loop. Also note the window listener for load. By using this event we can add multiple events, in the order the events were defined, in this case, the order in which scripts were loaded.